# Simple Obfuscation Of String Constants in Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I am not a F
lash expert.

I have a FLA file of a game coded in ActionScript 3.

The game has a string inside, `"www.mywebsite.com"`.

I want that when someone opens this FLA and searches for ".com" or "mywebsite.com" to find nothing. So I have decided to encode that string somehow. But I never coded in Flash, so I have no idea what to start with and Google isn't helping.

Basically all I want to do is replace this line:

```
var url1 = 'www.mywebsite.com';
```

With something like this and be functional.

```
var url1 = base64_decode('asdahwiyadwaeawr==');
```

Even a XOR or other simple string manipulation algorithm would be good.

What options do I have without importing any non-standard libraries into Flash?

Comment: No duplicate here. That was an example I asked for. Read again and be helpful maybe? I asked for a solution without requiring to add a library. The topic you suggested is requiring me to add a library to this.

Comment: @nevergone, -1 for not being willing to add a library to solve your problem.  It's the most reasonable way to accomplish the problem.

Comment: @nevergone I thought that the Base64 encoder was a built-in feature; I didn't realize that it was part of the official but not built-in Flex library.

Comment: What's the problem of importing external libraries? If someone wrote a `base64_decode()` for you, why roll your own?

Comment: Clarification: Are the strings guaranteed to be ASCII/byte-sized, or may they include other unicode characters? (Which would not be handled by a binary encoding like base64.)

Comment: Well, I do not want to import external libraries. I can add an internal class/function, that isnt the problem. But I dont want to import external files/libraries.


@JeremyBanks the string is guaranteed to be ASCII/byte-sized. I do not know if base64_encode or decode is a built-in function. That is why I ask for help. As far as I know it is available only through as3crypto. But I am not a flash expert and I do not know for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anyone looking through your code at something like `var url = BlaBla_decode("cvxcvxc");` can simply replace it with `var url = "www.HisWebsite.com`...

So I guess you're supposing no one will be going through your script line by line but instead search for ".com" (Which would make him a really lazy jerk)!

A simple solution is to come up with a function that would return "www.MyWebsite.com" without writing it;
Something like:

```
var url:String = youAreStupid();

function youAreStupid():String
{
    return String(f(22) + f(22) + f(22) + "extra.extra" + f(12) + f(24) + f(22) + f(4) + f(1) + f(18) + f(8) + f(19) + f(4) + "extra.extra" + f(2) + f(14) + f(12)).replace(/extra/g, "");
}

function f(n:Number):String
{
    return String.fromCharCode("a".charCodeAt(0) + n);
}
```

I can't but say this would be lame way to protect your document, and I suggest you keep a comment at the top of your Script (something clearly visible) : `// You won't find it YOU ARE STUPID`
Now if he's smart enough to search for `youAreStupid`, that means he's entitled to change it :p

**Of course there's also the simpler:**

```
String("-Ow-Mw-Gw-!.-Ym-Oy-Uw-Ae-Rb-Es-Si-Ot-Se-T.-Uc-Po-Im-D").replace(/-./g, "");
```

**but that's no fun!!!**